# a very basic definition cannot be found in most abstract algebra books

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, definition

I am looking for a precise definition of what is meant by an "algebra".

The reason is that I want to compare the difference between an "algebra" and other algebraic structures, i.e. a group, ring, field etc.

I have found the definitions of the others in books, while I haven't been able to find the definition of an algebra, surprisingly.

The only thing I found is in Folland's book on real analysis, p.21:

> "An algebra of sets on some nonempty set $X$ is a nonempty collection
>   $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$ that is closed under finite unions and
>   complements..."

I hope someone can help.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field.

Comment: but shouldn't 'algebra' different from 'algebra over a field'?

Comment: If you're comparing its definition (as an algebraic structure) to groups, rings, fields, then "algebra over a field" is almost certainly "the thing with algebra in it's name" that you're looking for.

Comment: For a broad treatment of the meaning of *algebra* in mathematics, both as a branch with many topics and as the name (often qualified, for clarity) of algebraic structures, the [Wikipedia article *Algebra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra) is a nice introduction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several things called *algebra* in mathematics, including these:

- [Algebra over a field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field): a ring that is also a vector space.
- [Algebra of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets): a collection of sets closed under the usual set operations.
- [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra): a collection of sets closed under countably many set operations.
- [Algebra (or algebraic structure)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra): the general object of study of universal algebra.